# tsql - delete last row

Tags: t-sql

I want to delete the last row from the table that satisfies some condition.

```
DELETE TOP 1 FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE SOME_COULMN = @VALUE
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Reverse your order and delete the first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE UNIQUE_ID = 
(SELECT TOP 1 UNIQUE_ID
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE SOME_COLUMN = @VALUE
ORDER BY SOMETHING DESC)
```

Answer (score -1):

DELETE and UPDATE statements require parentheses () for the number of rows argument

DELETE TOP **(1)** FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE SOME_COULMN = @VALUE
ORDER BY 1 DESC